# Use wildfly (Jboss 8) with Intellij Idea

Tags: java, jboss, intellij-idea, wildfly

I just needed to upgrade my Jboss Server to 8 (http://www.wildfly.org/) and I'd like to know if there is any way to use it like Jboss6-7 in Intellij ?

When i try to add a Jboss server I get the message : "The selected directory is not a valid 
Jboss home" (I select the folder up to all subfolders, like I do for any other jboss server).

The server configuration seems to be the same as Jboss 7 (folders, files)

**ANSWER :** Works nicely with Intellij Idea 132.425 (Cardea) preview

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in recently released WildFly 8 Beta1
get it at http://www.wildfly.org/download/

For now we have workaround in WildFly to make Idea believe it is still "jboss as"

Comment: Ok. I Use Intellij 13 preview for my project and will get back to my Intellij 12 when it will be final release (or I'll upgrade my licence to 13 when it will be final). Thanks for the info